# How to add a lot of information regarding clients

Tags: sql, erd

I am very new to SQL.  I am designing my first database for Projects at the architectural firm I work at.  I have created the ERD.  They will not let me insert it however, because I only have 5 points.
Now, the management wants to add the following information regarding clients:

```
                            ACTIVE CLIENTS
                            - how they found us
                            - time frame for project to start
                            - type/style
                            - why they chose us/contacted us
                            - project refernce
                            - budget
                            - primary or secondary residence
                            - project size
                            PAST CLIENTS
                            - last time contacted
                            - 
                            POTENTIAL CLIENTS
                            - how they found us
                            - time frame for project to start
                            - budget
                            - project size
                            - last contacted/who/when/how
                            LOST CLIENTS
                            - why (see below)
                              - cost/fees
                              - compatability
                              - time frame/availability
                              - no answer
                              - design style/other firm
                              - other
```

My question is this:
Should these be different tables called ActiveClients, PastClients, PotentialClients and LostClients?
If not, are they just part of the Client table?

If they are separate tables, do their primary keys show up as foreign keys in the Client table?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Keep it normalized.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  It might be worth your while to become familiar with design principles before doing any work.  Remember, it takes less time to do something well than to do it twice.

Comment: SusanE.Russel, while @DanBracuk's answer might not tell you specifically what to do in this scenario, the general advice might actually be more helpful in the long run.  The book he mentions would give you a good idea how to design this yourself - after all, random people on the internet aren't the ones on the ground at your project, you are.  A rough sketch (like my answer below) might point you in the right direction, but internalizing the knowledge and logic will help you far more.

Comment: I have read some of that book and taken a class in SQL.  Answering questions just to get points????

Comment: Nope ... I answered the question because I thought it might be helpful.  If you disagree, there's no obligation to award anything, and you can downvote if you feel like it. Glad to hear you've read the book (that means you're significantly ahead of a large number of people who have asked similar questions and thoroughly jaded the people who have been here a while), and hope you are able to find a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely don't put the various client types in different tables - what if you have to move a client from one status to another?

There are details about a client that you can put in other tables: for example, you could use tables to store the client status and client loss reason, & you could use a table with the residence (one row for primary, one for secondary).

[image]

`Residence` (or `Address`) is a table with an address in it; contains a clientID and a flag to say whether it's the primary residence

`ClientStatus` is a list table containing `ClientStatus` (Past, Active, Potential, Lost) & `ClientStatusID`

`ClientLossReason` is another list table containing `ClientLossReason` (Cost, Compabitibility, Time Frame, Design Style, Other, Unknown) and `ClientLossReasonID`

`Client` contains the core detail about a client (last contact date, source, etc.).

`Project` contains details about projects, including the ClientID (after all, a client could have more than one ..)

Etc.